# Calling PHP function using ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am calling a php function using ajax call but its not working. I have a table with some rows when I click on any column of a row it becomes editable with its value but when I edit the value and click on another column or enter the changed value is not displayed again. Actually I am doing an ajax call where I change the data of the column in my table but its not calling that php function.

My script is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".edit_tr").click(function()
    {
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        $("#span_"+ID).hide();
        $("#input_"+ID).show();
    }).change(function()
    {
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        var input=$("#input_"+ID).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&data='+input;
        $("#span_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />'); // Loading image

        if(input.length>0)
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "worker_app::edit_ajax()",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#span_"+ID).html(span);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Enter something.');
        }

    });

    // Edit input box click action
    $(".editbox").mouseup(function()
    {
        return false
    });

    // Outside click action
    $(document).mouseup(function()
    {
        $(".editbox").hide();
        $(".text").show();
    });

});
```

The HTML table looks like this

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="{IDWORKERS}" class="edit_tr">
    <td class="edit_td">
      <span id="span_{IDWORKERS}" class="text">{FIRM}</span>
      <input type="text" value="{FIRM}" class="editbox" id="input_{IDWORKERS}" />
    </td> 
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the php function is inside apps folder in a file called wroker_app.php

```
public function edit_ajax(){
    ///echo "<pre>";
    ///print_r($_POST);
    //echo "</pre>";
   // sql to update the database goes here
    echo 'I am here';
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know nothing happens :( I am new to ajax how can I check the ajax call ?

Comment: alert(html) inside success and tell us the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant call a php function like this. You can only call a php file where you can decide which function should be executed.
A simple example:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "/apps/worker_app.php",
 data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success: function(html) {
   $("#span_"+ID).html(span);
 }
});
```

And in your apps/worker_app.php:

```
<?php 

function edit_ajax(){
  echo 'I am here';
}

// You can put some logic before this line to decide which function to call based on the request
edit_ajax();
```

Comment: You can write it before the function i've just copied your code and added the call.

Comment: I write edit_ajax(); just before my function and it is giving me a syntax error :(

Comment: Paste the error message here, but the place of the call can't be the problem

Comment: I set my url in the ajax call like this url: "/apps/worker_app.php",
in my apps/worker_app file i have my method edit_ajax()and just before the start of this function I have edit_ajax(); The error it gives is 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp\www\personal\apps\worker_app.php on line 549

Comment: Oh than you cant simply call edit_ajax() you have to call it on an instance of the class (or call the static way if it's a static function)

Comment: should i create an object of class worker_app and then call edit_ajax with that object

Comment: Yep. But i think the error you got was because you put the function call in the class between two methods. You have to put it outside of the class (try after the closing bracket)

Comment: You mean I should write this 
$obj = new worker_app();
$obj->edit_ajax();
outside the class ?

Comment: One more thing is the data option in the ajax call can be checked as $_GET variable in my function ?

Comment: You can check in the $_POST array because you used the POST method.

Comment: but the array come to be empty and I am sending id and input value in the dataString ... How can I get the ID and the new input value in my edit_ajax function

Comment: Change this line: 
var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&data='+input;
to this: 
var dataString = {id: ID, data: input};

Comment: Sorry i edited the post because i submitted early now it's on the previous comment. But here it is again: var dataString = {id: ID, data: input};

Comment: When I refresh my page it execute edit_function method in which i have print_r($_POST)... The array comes out to be empty ... are the post variable set when I change a value in any column ?

Answer (score 2):

You can not call specific functions using the request alone. You need to tell your script that edit_ajax is supposed to be executed.

So change your url to worker_app.php, listen for the request using a (e.g) get variable like ?[function].

```
if (isset($_GET['edit_ajax']) && function_exists($_GET['edit_ajax']))
     edit_ajax();
```

Comment: It seems that you try to call the edit_ajax() by requesting the url /worker_app::edit_ajax.php. This is not possible. You can not call functions using the request url alone.

Comment: then what can I do to call a function ?

Comment: Call url: '/worker_app.php?edit_ajax'. In your worker_app.php file, listen for the call by the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

url: "worker_app::edit_ajax.php" 

Where is this url referrs to.

check this reference 
[jquery .ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

If you want to call function use try to post any specific post field to that file.
After use below in that file

```
 if($_POST['field']!="") { 
      requredfunction () {
           // your code run here
       } 
}
```